# Bootstrap. List + ScrollSpy. How to reduce height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following template.

[Click here](http://www.bootply.com/88R9VG4Y7y)

I need to reduce the height of each item on the list from left-sidebar so that they can all be visible. I need to show 25 items total.

No matter what I change so far, I does not affect the look of the list.

Can you help?

Comment: That's not a very responsive way to display the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your CSS:

```
.nav li a{
     padding:0px 15px;
}
```

However note that this will overwrite padding for all `<a>` tags that are child elements of `<nav>` and `<li>`